# Why gunzipping a 644 file belonging to root is possible by user and gunzipped file belongs to user

Tags: linux, gzip

A tar.gz file belonging to root, can be  gunzipped by a user, since it is readable by group and public. However after gunzipping, the tar file owner is user, not root anymore. Is it a feature of the program gunzip? or is there another mechanism?

Comment: how is a normal user supposed to create files or folders that belong to someone else? This is normal behaviour.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I was expecting a separate tar file creation since user cannot write to the original file. I updated the title.

Comment: @YvonHuynh I don't understand what you're saying. The user read root's tar.gz file and created his own tar file. What's the mystery?

Comment: If I understand correctly the `.tar` file is created by the user, but the original `.tgz` file vanishes. Who is the owner of the folder where this happens? And what are the permissions? Please add `ls -la` on that folder.

Comment: @YvonHuynh Is your question how someone other than the owner of a file was able to remove that file from a directory? The answer is that removing a file from a directory is an operation on a directory.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thank you for the clarification,I have a tendency to compare with Windows way of working and forget Linux is way different

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes it's exactly that

Comment: @DavidSchwartz uhm, it's the same with windows. To delete files you only need permissions on the containing folder, not on the files themselves.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider A long time ago, Windows was different and followed the DOS semantics. I believe it switched to UNIX semantics when NTFS was introduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most modern operating systems, including Linux, there is no operation to delete a file. There is an operation to remove a file from a directory (called "unlink"), but it's an operation on the directory, not the file. So if you can modify a directory, you can remove files from it or add files (new ones, or existing ones that you can access) to it.

Deletion of a file is done automatically by the file system when it is no longer in use. A single file can even be added to more than one directory, in which case it cannot be deleted until it is removed from all such directories and is no longer in use by any processes.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answer of David, but here are my 5 cents:

To unzip a file, you need following permissions:

- to be able to read the input file.
- to be able to create output file.
- optionally, you might want to `chown` output file

Since you are normal user, you can not `chown` file to root. By this reason unzipped file is owned by your user.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question was very unclear. What he was trying to ask is how a normal user was able to delete a file owned by root. Of course, the user didn't do that, they just removed it from their own directory. The file system deleted the file because it was unreachable.

Comment: I updated title hoping it's more clear